# Bitrise - Could not receive latest API key from App Store Connect, this might be a server issue

Tags: ios, authentication, build, provisioning-profile, bitrise

I'm trying to upload iOS build from Bitrise, and got the error as mentioned in the title. Below is the screenshot from bitrise.io :

[image]

I came to know from few posts around that it might be due to 2 factor authentication. But it was working fine and getting uploaded successfully few days back. Not sure whats causing the issue now, or should retrying upload will work ?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a change in the URL of the authentication between services. This was fixed right away in the latest version of the Auto Provision step, make sure you update to that, that should solve this

Comment: Always good to be specific. "latest version" means which version ? Latest version will change in the future making the answer irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Pratham! This change was implemented in the AutoProvision version 1.4.0 I believe.

However, this will remain true all future versions, so whenever you do experience this issue, updating to the latest version of the step at any given time will solve it 